# Question about a built in function named SKAction.moveTo

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
let moveShipOnTheScreenAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height*0.2, duration: 0.5)
```

The above line is weird when I test it on the iPad. It goes to the front and then just goes back to its original position.

```
let startPoint = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
```

But I don't have that problem when I test it on all the other iPhones.
There it just goes from the `startpoint` to `moveShipOnTheScreenAction`.

I already tried to not include the `moveShipOnTheScreenAction` and just set the `startPoint` the same as the position where `moveShipOnTheScreenAction` always ends, and it isn't weird.

Maybe my player values aren't on the right place.

```
player.setScale(delta + 0.1)
player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: 0 - player.size.height)
player.zPosition = 2
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)
player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Player
player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.None
player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Enemy
pointOfTouch = CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: player.position.y)
self.addChild(player)
```

Comment: That first line can't do anything - it's just creating an action. also it's a `moveTo` so it's effect when applied(i.e. how much the node moves)  will depend on where the node is when the SKaction is applied.

Comment: i meant my node does move to the correct position but only on ipad it goes straight back to its original position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt fix the issue but i worked around it by changing the default position and gave the player an alpha value of 0 also before the game started I changed the position back to its original position and also gave the player an alpha value of 1.